# How to Use SwiftyDropbox's "destination" with a Download

Tags: dropbox-api

In reviewing the [SwiftyDropbox tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/swift#tutorial) in the v2 Dropbox API, it shows how to perform a download:

```
// Download a file
let destination : (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> NSURL = { temporaryURL, response in
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    // generate a unique name for this file in case we've seen it before
    let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let pathComponent = "\(UUID)-\(response.suggestedFilename!)"
    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
}

client.files.download(path: "/MyFile.db", destination: destination).response { response, error in
    if let (metadata, url) = response {
        print("*** Download file ***")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        print("Downloaded file name: \(metadata.name)")
        print("Downloaded file url: \(url)")
        print("Downloaded file data: \(data)")
    } else {
        print(error!)
    }
}
```

I'm unclear what's going on with the `destination` part. Why do I need to generate a random string for the filename?

When I try to specify my own filename, the download doesn't seem to work:

```
let destination : (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> NSURL = { temporaryURL, response in
  let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
  return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyFile.db")
}
```

I want to download a file from Dropbox named `MyFile.db` and I want to put it in my device's documents directory with the name `MyFile.db` and overwrite it if it's already there.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say it doesn't seem to work, I expect you mean you get an error like this:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“CFNetworkDownload_bPYhu1.tmp” couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=..., NSUserStringVariant=(
>      Move
>   ), NSDestinationFilePath=..., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fda0a67cea0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}

SwiftyDropbox, by virtue of using AlamoFire, doesn't currently let you overwrite files using the `download` function.

Specifically, SwiftyDropbox [calls `download`](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/blob/e2c9d1ccd1fea897cb93132de824a7e7b975a52e/Source/Client.swift#L306) in AlamoFire, and AlamoFire [calls `NSFileManager.moveItemAtURL`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/990fded98afe5135dc418e1f6eb0287027dd067f/Source/Download.swift#L200). The documentation for [`NSFileManager.moveItemAtURL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/moveItemAtURL:toURL:error:) says:

> If an item with the same name already exists at dstURL, this method aborts the move attempt and returns an appropriate error.

So, it seems like it's just being cautious, and making it hard for your app to accidentally overwrite (ad potentially lose) data. If you definitely know you want to overwrite a particular file, you'll need to do so explicitly, after the Dropbox API call. We'll consider this a feature request though.

---

Update: SwiftyDropbox now offers the ability to overwrite the files directly as of [version 3.1.0](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox/releases/tag/3.1.0), e.g., using [download(path:rev:overwrite:destination:)](https://dropbox.github.io/SwiftyDropbox/api-docs/latest/Classes/FilesRoutes.html#/s:FC13SwiftyDropbox11FilesRoutes8downloadFT4pathSS3revGSqSS_9overwriteSb11destinationFTCSo5NSURLCSo17NSHTTPURLResponse_S1__GCS_19DownloadRequestFileCCS_5Files22FileMetadataSerializerCS4_23DownloadErrorSerializer_).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. And after I overwrite it, I assume that also means I can safely delete the temporary file that Dropbox creates in my Documents directory?

Comment: Sure, that should be fine. It's yours to use as you wish.